# Apache log4J properties from another property file

Tags: apache, log4j

I want to set the DB user `name/password` in `Apache log4J` properties file reading from  another property file.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Log4j property file is not place where you should place DB username/password. Did you mean in regular property file?

Comment: In Our project, we need to save the logs into the DB .So for that we added DB connection details in log4j property file

Since we already have another property file with DB details.Is it possible to read the DB username/password from that property file.

Comment: log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=root
log4j.appender.DB.sql=insert into     coupon(couponId,customerName,date,level,message) values("%X{couponId}","%X{customerName}","%d","%p","%m")
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches comes to my mind about potential solution for your problem:

1) Use [Programmatic configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) for Log4J. 
In this case, you would read DB properties from your configuration file at the application startup and then build your Log4J with these values using programmatic configuration instead of configuration file.

2) [Write your own custom appender](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073104/learn-java/write-custom-appenders-for-log4j.html) by extending [JDBCAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html). You can implement your own method to read data from the provided property file which will initialize other parameters, e.g. url, databasename, password, username...

Hope this helps.